# react-native-ble-plx app only works when connected to metro

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler, react-native-ble-plx

I'm working on a react-native-ble-plx app, and the app connects to the device just fine when connected to metro, but doesn't connect at all when I close metro. The app still shows up, it just can't connect to the bluetooth peripheral anymore. Even if I build the app with metro and close out of metro later, it still doesn't work.

Why would my code change functionality at all without the presence of metro?

Answer (score 1):

When using React Native, Metro is responsible for bundling and serving the JavaScript bundle for the app during development. The app running on the device or simulator is then able to communicate with Metro over a WebSocket connection to receive updates to the JavaScript code and other resources as they change.

Based on the behavior you're describing, it's possible that the issue is related to the way the Bluetooth module is being initialized in your app. When Metro is running, the Bluetooth module is able to initialize and connect to the peripheral device as expected, but when Metro is not running, the initialization process may be failing for some reason, preventing the connection from being established.

One possible explanation could be that the Bluetooth module is relying on some resource or configuration that is being provided by Metro during development, but is not available when the app is built and deployed outside of Metro. For example, if the module is using a configuration file that is generated by Metro during development, that file may not be available when the app is built and deployed without Metro.

To investigate further, you could try debugging the initialization process of the Bluetooth module and see if any errors are being thrown or if any configuration resources are missing. You could also try running the app on a physical device and connecting to it via USB debugging to see if the behavior is the same as when running on a simulator.

Another approach would be to modify your code to include more detailed logging or error handling, which may help identify the root cause of the issue.